Quarkus Rest Client MTLS configuration guide
Where can I find the guide for setting up MTLS on REST clients?
In the past, it was at https://es.quarkus.io/version/main/guides/rest-client.

Is this here maybe what you're searching for? https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authentication-mechanisms#mutual-tls
Or here also a tutorial can be found: https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-mutual-tls/

thanks @ph1l but the former refers to server side configuration and the former, even if it is for client side, refers to Microprofile instead of Quarkus REST client. Issue at quarkus.io
